# Swift Core Data Relationships and Seeding Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I am currently parsing JSON data and either updating or creating an entity based on whether a results exists.

I am using SwiftyJson for my JSON parsing.

I have a createInManagedObjectContext function inside my NSManagedObject Subclass that accepts a bunch of parameters for creating a new record:

```
 class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, id: String, flatNumber: String, propertyName: String, propertyNumber: String, street: String, locality: String, town: String, postcode:String, createdDate: NSString) -> Work {
        let newWorkItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Work", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Work

        var mydate = createdDate
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"

        newWorkItem.createdDate = formatter.dateFromString(mydate as String)!



        newWorkItem.id = id
        newWorkItem.flatNumber = flatNumber
        newWorkItem.propertyName = propertyName
        newWorkItem.propertyNumber = propertyNumber
        newWorkItem.street = street
        newWorkItem.locality = locality
        newWorkItem.town = town
        newWorkItem.postcode = postcode

        return newWorkItem
    }
```

and here is the code I am currently using to parse the json and create a new record:

```
 if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
    moc.performBlockAndWait({
        Work.createInManagedObjectContext(moc,
            id: object["Id"].stringValue,
            flatNumber: object["FlatNumber"].stringValue,
            propertyName: object["PropertyName"].stringValue,
            propertyNumber: object["PropertyNumber"].stringValue,
            street: object["Street"].stringValue,
            locality: object["Locality"].stringValue,
            town: object["Town"].stringValue,
            postcode: object["Postcode"].stringValue,
            createdDate: object["CreatedDate"].stringValue

        )

        for party in object["Parties"].arrayValue {

            Party.createInManagedObjectContext(moc,
                id: party["Id"].stringValue,
                firstName: party["FirstName"].stringValue,
                lastName: party["LastName"].stringValue,
                propertyName: party["PropertyName"].stringValue,
                propertyNumber: party["PropertyNumber"].stringValue,
                street: party["Street"].stringValue,
                locality: party["Locality"].stringValue,
                town: party["Town"].stringValue,
                postcode: party["Postcode"].stringValue,
                createdDate: party["CreatedDate"].stringValue)

        }
        // println(object["Parties"])



    })
    moc.save(nil)
}
```

Now I know this isn't the best way of doing this kind of operation, and in honesty this schema is going to be quite big, there will be a lot of records in other entities that will rely on this Work entity.

I thought I would begin with parties as there can be many parties, but I am unsure as to how to link each party with the Work entity. I did experiment with passing in the workId and thought perhaps I need to pass in a Work object back into the Work managed object but I am positive there are far better approaches than having sprawling functions such as these?

So my question is, what would be the best approach in this situation to handle creating entities with multiple relationships?

**Update:**

I have changed my implementation as follows:

let work = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Work", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Work

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"

work.id = object["Id"].stringValue
work.flatNumber = object["FlatNumber"].stringValue
work.propertyName = object["PropertyName"].stringValue
work.propertyNumber = object["PropertyNumber"].stringValue
work.street =  object["Street"].stringValue
work.locality = object["Locality"].stringValue
work.town = object["Town"].stringValue
work.postcode = object["Postcode"].stringValue
work.createdDate = formatter.dateFromString(object["CreatedDate"].stringValue)!


for obj in object["Parties"].arrayValue {
    let party = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Party", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Party



    party.id = obj["Id"].stringValue
    party.firstName = obj["FirstName"].stringValue
    party.lastName =  obj["LastName"].stringValue
    party.propertyName = obj["PropertyName"].stringValue
    party.propertyNumber = obj["PropertyNumber"].stringValue
    party.street = obj["Street"].stringValue
    party.locality = obj["Locality"].stringValue
    party.town = obj["Town"].stringValue
    party.postcode = obj["Postcode"].stringValue
    party.createdDate = formatter.dateFromString(obj["CreatedDate"].stringValue)!

    //doesn't work
    work.parties.addlistObject(party)

}
```

I did try implementing the NSSet solution described below but ran into problems where the current for loop that is iterating over my JSON is running

**Edit:**

I have managed to get it working by adding

```
  party.work = work as Work
```

Inside the for loop as suggested below.

Now it runs fine for a while and seems to be doing the right thing until it falls over with an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Is this a separate or related issue?

Comment: That error message simply means that there was a value that was nil, but its variable was not optional (i.e: testVar or testVar! instead of testVar?). Could you post a photo of the error log or the debug panel to the left when the error occurs? You can usually trace the error back to see what methods were called and at what line in code the error occurred.

Comment: ahh, thanks yeah i solved it, i'll need to check all my JSON for any null values in the future

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is actually pretty simple with Core Data. What you are asking for is a way to connect two entities together with one another.

Now, it seems as if you want multiple Parties under a Work entity. This means you are looking at a To-Many relation between the Work entity and the Parties entity. All you need to do is create a relationship between the two entities that will look like this:

[image: To-Many Relationship]

**First**, go you your Work entity under the "Relationships" tab and click the "**+**" button. Name this new relationship "**parties**" and then click enter. Make the destination your Parties entity.

**Second**, go to your Parties entity and do the same, naming the relationship "**work**" and setting its destination to your Work entity. But this time, click the drop-down menu under "Inverse" and select your parties relationship to form a To-One relation beween your Work and Parties entities. Now, each instance of your Work entity holds a variable that holds an instance of the opposite Parties entity and vice versa.

[image: Entity Relationships]

However, you probably want multiple instances of your "Parties" entity connected you one Work instance, and so now you want to change the relationship to a To-Many relation. We can do this by going to your Work entity and clicking on the "parties" relation. Now, in the Data Model Inspector to the right, look for the menu that says "**Type**". Click on the menu and choose "To Many" from the drop-down.

[image: To-Many Relation]

You now have a To-Many relationship between entities!

Now, to add the connection in code, open your Parties.swift file and, at the bottom, type:

```
@NSManaged var work: Work
```

This gives a reference to the work object that the party is connected to. You can set this while creating your Parties instance in `for party in object["Parties"].arrayValue ... }`. Just use

```
party.work = {Your Work instance}
```

For the Work class, however, things are slightly different. You see, the way we have set up our relationship, the Parties entity can only be under one work entity but the Work entity can contain many Parties. Core Data will store these as an NSSet (or NSOrderedSet if you want to order the Parties objects in the set). So add this code to the bottom of Work.swift:

```
@NSManaged var parties: NSSet
```

This creates an NSSet instance that will contain all Parties under the Work instance. Now you can add a party by creating a new NSSet instance and assigning it to the parties variable like so:

```
let newSet = NSMutableSet(setWithSet: parties)
newSet.addObject({party variable})
myWork.parties = newSet.copy() as! NSSet
```

You can then, if you have a workID, check the ID by using `myParty.work.workID == "SomeWorkID"`. You can also enumerate through the parties NSSet if you need to.

Hopefully this answer helps you with what you're trying to accomplish! Let me know if this doesn't answer your question fully.

If you want to do more researching about CoreData relationships, you can get a book on Core Data (I bought "Core Data by Tutorials" by Ray Wenderlich) or look over Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html).

Comment: I'm still having an issue creating a relationship, please see my update